# Will Python3.6 be deleted if I upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20?

Tags: upgrade, python

I have Ubuntu 18 and python 3.6, I also installed python3.8 manually.

Now I need to upgrade to Ubuntu 20, I'd like to check if python3.6 will be deleted or kept?

Will python3.8 be default after the upgrade? What's the difference as to python installation/version between fresh installation of Ubuntu 20 and upgrading to Ubuntu 20?

Thanks.

Comment: Your products using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20) when upgraded do not have  user level applications changed during the *release-upgrade* process, ie. they're different to a 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade for example. The *snap* packages that run on a Ubuntu Core 16 system are identical to those running on Ubuntu Core 22 (or any other *year* release).

Comment: "*What's the difference as to python installation/version between fresh installation of Ubuntu 20 and upgrading to Ubuntu 20?*" What leads you to believe there is a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you release-upgrade a stock install of Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, the Python 3.6 packages will be *replaced* by Python 3.8 packages.

Ubuntu 18.04 requires Python 3.6.

Ubuntu 20.04 requires Python 3.8.

Comment: may I say it in another way: python3.6 will be deleted, python 3.8 will be installed?

Comment: Yes, that is why the term *replaced* was used.